# Big slowdown on ios7: CGContextDrawImage or UIView setImage?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, cgcontext

Ok, I have a serious problem with ios7. I have a code where the user drags a control, and as he drags, the interface is updated with a processed image. This was very fast until iOS 6.1, and now it's very slow.

Here's how my code works:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //get initial position

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //calculates new position

    applyEffects();

- (void)applyEffects {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext();
    //CGContextTranslateCTM, CGContextScaleCTM, CGContextDrawImage and stuff like that
    UIImage *blendedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    preview.image = blendedImage; //preview is a UIImageView
```

Now the thing is, after logging, I realized applyEffects is getting called every time I move the finger on screen, but the view is being updated very very few times, and I think that's why it appears so slow.

So, any idea on why "preview.image = blendedImage;" is not updating the view anymore? Am I missing something?

Again, this only happens on iOS 7.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed my applyEffects to this:

```
dispatch_queue_t myQueue = dispatch_queue_create("My Queue",NULL);

if (!running) {
    running = true;

    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext();
        //CGContextTranslateCTM, CGContextScaleCTM, CGContextDrawImage and stuff like that
        UIImage *blendedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // Update the UI
            preview.image = blendedImage;
            running = false;
        });
    });
}
```

Now it will create a separate thread to apply the effect, and update the UI when it's ready. This way I'm not clogging up the UI touch event processing.

The if (!running) is a dumb control to make it only run once at a time.

The ideal way is to throw away all that code and reimplement it with GPUImage, but it will require much more time, so it's a temporary solution.

Comment: You can try to draw inside the 'drawRect:' method.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, I had the same issue and this helped me resolve it. I was wondering though if you found any Apple ios7 documentation to support why this is needed. I don't really understand why dispatching the setting of the UIImageView's image back on to the main queue (that was all I needed, I didn't need to do any prior work on my own custom queue) fixes what looks like a blocking issue. I thought the touches callbacks were also running on the main queue?

Comment: neils4fun: I don't get it either, but I stopped looking for the problem, because in my new applications I'm using GPUImage for these kind of operations... If you find out why this started happening, please post here, I'm curious as well

Comment: Interesting Paulo, that may be a hint and point to UIImage rather than UIImageView as being the culprit here. I've searching for related issues to get to the bottom of this but haven't come up with anything useful yet, but I'll look at it from the UIImage angle.